# Выключить/включить микрофон

Tags: javascript

Проект на Vue 3.
Запускаю стрим с помощью OvenLiveKit, перед этим проходит проверка на доступ к камере и микрофону. После чего меня редиректит на другую страницу, где отображается сам стрим через OvenPlayerVue3.
Необходимо добавить функционал отключения/включения микрофона, то есть чтобы для зрителей отключался звук.
Как это сделать?